# select / unselect all checkboxes in listview with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have listview control with checkboxs and checkbox for select all with paging in update panel 
the select - unselect all working fine except that when selecting in page 1 all elements selected but other pages not selected any ideas

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstvw_all" runat="server" DataKeyNames="para"  >
                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="tbl_pers">
                                                <tr class="rsgridh">
                                                    <th>
                                                        رقم الإداري
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        الاسم
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        مهمة العمل
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        الفرع
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        الدورة
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        عدد المتدربين
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        المبلغ المستحق
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                       <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="SelectAll(this);" />
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                                                </tr>


                                            </table>
                                        </LayoutTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr class="rsgridi">
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("per_no") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("per_name") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("job_desc") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("org_label") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("course_desc") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("cnt_all") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("intial_cost") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>

                                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbSelected"   Checked='<%# Selected(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"para")) %>'  ToolTip='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"para") %>' >
                                                    </asp:CheckBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>

                                         <tr class="rsgridai">
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("per_no") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("per_name") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("job_desc") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("org_label") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("course_desc") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("cnt_all") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%# Eval("intial_cost") %>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>

                                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server"   ID="cbSelected"  Checked='<%# Selected(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"para")) %>' ToolTip='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"para") %>' s>
                                                    </asp:CheckBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: can you paste your PageIndexChanging code here .

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done - When you are in page one, the rest pages are not actual exists.

When you ask to select all check boxes is mean what you see. After you change page the other check box are set to default (probably unchecked)

So re design your user interface for what you won to do.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a tweak ,this is for gridview ,convert this for listview or any other repeater control

Gridview HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"  
PageSize="5" Width="324px" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" 
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CS Codes

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  RememberOldValues();
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  BindData();
  RePopulateValues();
}
```

And

```
private void RememberOldValues()
{
  ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
  int index = -1;
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
   index = (int) GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
   bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked;

  // Check in the Session
  if (Session[CHECKED_ITEMS] != null)
   categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session[CHECKED_ITEMS];
  if (result)
  {
  if (!categoryIDList.Contains(index))
   categoryIDList.Add(index);
  }
  else
   categoryIDList.Remove(index);
  }
  if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
   Session[CHECKED_ITEMS] = categoryIDList;
}
```

And

```
private void RePopulateValues()
{
  ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session[CHECKED_ITEMS];
  if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
  {
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
   int index = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
  if (categoryIDList.Contains(index))
  {
   CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
   myCheckBox.Checked = true;
  }
  }
  }
}
```

Bind Data Code

```
/* QUERY */
private const string QUERY_SELECT_ALL_CATEGORIES = "SELECT * FROM Categories";

private void BindData()
{
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
  SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(QUERY_SELECT_ALL_CATEGORIES,
  myConnection);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ad.Fill(ds, "Categories");
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

For more details chk this [Maintaining_State_of_CheckBoxes](http://aspalliance.com/774_Maintaining_State_of_CheckBoxes_While_Paging_in_a_GridView_Control.all)